# How will you join flat table and EAV table in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

How will you **join flat** table and **EAV table** in Magento?

Answer (score 2):

```
$productCollection->joinTable(
    array('bonus' => 'mycompany/bonus'), 'product_id=entity_id',
    array('bonus_id' => 'bonus_id')
);
```

**The parameters are:**

> public function joinTable($table, $bind, $fields = null, $cond = null,
>   $joinType = 'inner')

Table is easy, it is the magento **namespace/entity** format, which you use in your configuration, resource models and the collection.

Bind means, the ON statement in your SQL

You can use an array of the format  **array('alias' => 'namespace/entity')**

It is important to have your flat table **BEFORE** and your EAV table **AFTER** the equal sign. Don't use main_table. before the attribute. Magento will do this for you.

Fields is an array. If you use a string instead, you get this:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in
>   /var/www/magento-1.6.2.0/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php
>   on line 775.

You can use an array of the format **array('field1', 'field2', '...')** or  **array('alias' => 'field1', '...')**

Condition is a * WHERE ON condition* in the SQL.

Source: fabian-blechschmidt